# CakePHP: Advantages of adding CSS to CSS block instead of using inline output when using HtmlHelper?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I started to learn CakePHP a few days ago, following their blog tutorial.
Now I am in the process of writing a small project for myself to get familiar with the framework.

Having studied their documentation, I noticed there are two ways to include CSS files.
One way is to echo the link tag(s) using the HtmlHelper: `echo $this->Html->css(array('style', 'forms', 'modal'));`. That type of linking is referred to as 'inline style' according to the options array.

The other method is to add the tags to the (I believe default?) CSS block and then print that block inside the `<head>`:

```
echo $this->Html->css(array('style', 'forms', 'modal'), array('inline' => false));
echo $this->fetch('css');
```

**What are the advantages of using one way over the other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following layout file:

```
...
<head>
...
<?= $this->Html->css('main.css'); ?>
<?= $this->fetch('css'); ?>
...
</head>
...
```

### The simplest way

By default the rendered view would contain:

```
...
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>
```

If there is no logic associated with whether a css file should be added - it's appropriate to simply edit the layout file and add the css file, ignoring the `inline` property.

**Advantage**: It's simple, clear and obvious what's happening

### The Dynamic way

If however there is logic associated with whether a particular css file should be included - this is where the `inline` property becomes useful.

Consider the following view file:

```
<?php
if ($something) {
    $this->Html->css('maps.css', ['inline' => false]);
    echo $this->element('maps');
}
?>
View contents
```

Or a plugin which includes the following helper:

```
<?php
class AwesomeHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function beforeLayout() {
        $this->Html->css('awesome.css', ['inline' => false]);
        $this->Html->js('awesome.js', ['inline' => false]); // also applies to js files
    }
}
```

In these cases without using the inline property or editing the layout file, it's not possible to add the css files to the head of the rendered output. However by using the inline property, it is possible to build up the css files required for the final view.

**Advantage**: Code outside the layout file can add required css files to the output *in the head*.